# Алгоритм действий приложения после запроса разрешений

Tags: android-permissions

Перед использованием приложения, необходимо сделать запрос разрешений. Не могу определить момент когда все попытки закончились и вместо запроса разрешений необходимо показать стандартное окно системных настроек приложения.
Переменные: `boolean isDenied` - разрешение отсутствует `boolean isShouldShow` - необходимо предоставить пользователю разъяснение зачем нужно разрешение.

| isDenied | isShouldShow | Что нужно сделать | Результат запроса |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | false | запрос разрешения | запрет |
| true | true | объяснение и снова запрос разрешения | снова запрет |
| true | false | открыть системные настройки приложения |  |

Не могу идентифицировать последний пункт. Пробовал определить, что был выполнен первый запрос, но не получилось, потому что если ничего в запросе не нажимать, а просто отменить операцию кнопкой "назад", то `isShouldShow` не становится true.

Comment: Что значит все попытки? Она одна. Запретили - программа или дальше работает или нет. Ну или появляется стандартное окно настроек

Comment: @ArtyMorris, почему же одна? После первого запрета, если вызвать метод shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale он вернет true и можно снова сделать запрос.

Comment: Возможно, это я не пробовал